# gRPC c++ multiple outstanding requests

Tags: c++, grpc

I have a server/server app, where one server looks much like a client but is servicing requests from a client -- so I'll call it a client. There are several different rpc messages, lets call them resolve, bind, unbind. I'd like the client to be able to freely send resolve, bind, and unbind requests asynchronously, eventually getting responses. Do I need to use different channels for this (hope not), do I need to stream each -- that seems a bit odd as I'd like to be able to send resolve, bind, and unbind (with their payloads) free of having to wait for responses. Yes, I'll eventually process the responses (but at my leisure), generally only as part of cleanup or to forwarding to the real client. Is this reasonable using gRPC, do I need different channels, do I mark them all as (stream request-type) returns (stream response-type), or do I do something different?

Comment: I'm still in the architecture phase, trying to put the parts together to build a POC. My concern is that gRPC won't be able to do what I'd like it to do and would have to roll my own -- the thought of which makes me cringe. While I don't care about http/2 for this case, having the framework deal with timeouts, errors, and matching requests with responses is not something I want to duplicate.

Comment: "looks much like a client, but is servicing requests from a client -- so I'll call it a client". Can you please write the final situation ?

Comment: It's server to server, however, one server is making all the requests and the other server the responses. The requesting server ideally should be able to make additional requests, either resolve, bind or unbind, without needing to wait for the responses to previous resolve, bind or unbind requests.

Comment: Well, over the past few days I've put together the async stuff. The downside is that my server needs to handle different requests. So far, this has required that I have to allocate request/response on setup for each message and then delete/allocate new ones each time a corresponding request is handled. At least, that's my reading of the example using CallData. Am I wrong, or are they reusable?

Answer (score 0):

When you handle a rpc at an async server, you need something like CallData to maintain the context of a pending rpc. You can reuse the request and response objects but the ClientContext and ServerContext should not be reused.